# Python: Connecting to multiple BLE devices using Bleak

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, python-asyncio

I'm new to BLE device and asynchronous programming. So far, I have a toy program written that finds a BLE device by its name and can obtain/print data given the characteristic UUID:

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner
from bleak import BleakClient

device_name = 'XXX_name'
character_uuid = 'XXX_uuid' #character uuid

async def main():
    devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
    for device in devices:
            print(device.name)
            print(device.address)
            if device.name == device_name:
                myDevice = device
                print('found it')
                async with BleakClient(myDevice) as client:
                    if (not client.is_connected):
                        raise "client not connected"
                    # char_bytes = await client.read_gatt_char(character_uuid) 
                    # name = bytearray.decode(char_bytes)
                    # print('hex', char_bytes.hex(' '))
              

                    await client.start_notify(character_uuid, data_callback)
                    await asyncio.sleep(10)
                    await client.stop_notify(character_uuid)
            
def data_callback(handle, data):
    print(handle, data.hex(' '))

asyncio.run(main())
```

Once it finds the device, it listens to the data for 10 second and prints the data:

```
await client.start_notify(character_uuid, data_callback)
await asyncio.sleep(10)
await client.stop_notify(character_uuid)
```

I'm not clear on why the printed data above is different than the byte array I get using read_gatt_char():

```
char_bytes = await client.read_gatt_char(character_uuid) 
name = bytearray.decode(char_bytes)
print('hex', char_bytes.hex(' '))
```

Anyway, my main problems are:

1. The above code only listens to the data for 10 seconds (or whatever fixed time) and the program ends. I'd like the program to listen for data indefinitely till the user ends the program.
2. The above code only handles 1 device. In practice, there can be multiple BLE devices with the same name, and I'd like to program to listen to them all and log the data for each.
3. In order to save power, the BLE device in question auto shuts off after periods of inactivity, during which it cannot be discovered. Upon powering on again, I'd like to program to recognize that this device was seen before (same Mac address?) and start logging data again. I feel this would require the discover() method to be called constantly.

Can you give a high level overview on how to implement this? Do I need parallel programming or deal with threads?

Thanks

Comment: hi! having the same situation for 2 ESP32 devices over BLE. Did you resolve this? What was your approach?